# How to get the json data from url in odoo javascript

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

How to get the JSON data from url using JavaScript. I tried the following but it does not give the json data.

```
var GetLocation = function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } 
    else { 
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position, http) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var app_id = '6784429f5eff661309aaa5280a143f97';
    var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";
    var weather_api = api +"/weather?appid="+app_id+"&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&units=metric";
    // console.log(weather_api);
    var a = http.get(weather_api).then(function(response){
        position.jsonList=response.data;

    });
    console.log(a);


}
```

When print the weather_api it gives complete url but i am stuck in how to get the json data from that url.

Comment: Put the console log inside the callback function.  You're making a call, logging an unfinished promise, and then the call is completing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @John212 That has nothing to do with their problem.

Comment: What is `http`?

Comment: It is used to get the data because i refer from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lYxboRqaxk

Comment: I am getting the this http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=6784429f5eff661309aaa5280a143f97&lat=23.1932488&lon=72.6354726&units=metric but unable to get the json data bro @John212...

Comment: In ODOO, do they use AngularJS?

Comment: No, I am just trying.

Comment: @John212 I'm not angry.  I am telling you that you have not helped them because their problem is nothing to do with JSON.  They're expecting a result from `console.log(a);` which takes place before the asynchronous http request is completed.

Comment: Bro i know how to get the json data in python but don't know in JS.
Because in python directly we can use:
Import requests
a="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=6784429f5eff661309aaa5280a143f97&lat=23.1932488&lon=72.6354726&units=metric"
b=requests.get(a).json()
print(b)

Comment: In the video you've shared, they are using a framework called `AngularJS`. You have to use the same framework, then only the http module can be used. Or, you can create the same module yourself, with jQuery. Check my answer.

Comment: Can you tell me the solution bro.

Comment: Check my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things:

1. You have to understand Asynchronous call flow.
2. You have to understand everything in a tutorial, if you are following one.

`#1` Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for Asynchronous call flow. Then learn about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in JavaScript.

`#2` The tutorial you are following is using Angular.js, which has the built in `$http` module, which has a `get` method in it. In your case, looks like, you are not using Angular.js & also, `showPosition` function is getting called by `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, so that will not pass `http` module when calling `showPosition` function.

I have added a simple http module using `jQuery` library. So, to make this code work, you will have to include `jQuery` in your html file. In any case, the following code, must give you an understanding about creating objects & methods in JavaScript & you must be able to replace jQuery if you want some other library for HTTP requests.

```
var http = {
  get: function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      $.get(url, resolve).fail(reject);
    })
  }
};

var GetLocation = function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } 
    else { 
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var app_id = '6784429f5eff661309aaa5280a143f97';
    var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";
    var weather_api = api +"/weather?appid="+app_id+"&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&units=metric";
    // console.log(weather_api);
    var a = http.get(weather_api).then(function(response){
        position.jsonList=response;
        console.log(position.jsonList);
    });



}
```

Note: Notice that I have moved the `console.log` inside the promise handler.